# Primary Key across One to Many Schema

Tags: mysql, database, jpa

I have a simple question about schema design.  My application has a table of First names and last names - no other identifying information.  It is of course possible to have two distinct individuals with the same first and last name.  Each individual has one or more registration numbers that are persisted in a separate table.  The registration numbers are unique.  It troubles me that the Names table has no unique key (other than an auto-generated ID) and that the uniqueness of a record is really the combination of FirstName, LastName and the registration numbers.  First I am not sure how to create a key such as the one I describe and second I am not sure that it is necessary?  Is this design any more sustainable to corruption than one which has a unique (say registration number)?  Where this impacts is for updates - I need to search for the cross table combination of FirstName, LastName and registration number(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it both ways. Either by creating a unique key which I have explained below. The other is option is to use ID as a foreign key in the table where registration numbers are stored. While updating records you need to give the registration number plus the ID (which is Foreign Key in this table) in the where clause to update any record.

I would prefer you to create a Unique Key.

You can simply create a Unique Key based on the three columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Names(
     ID Int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     FirstName Varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     LastName Varchar (50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT Names_UC UNIQUE (ID, FirstName, LastName)
);
```

Or Alter command, in case you've already created a table:

```
ALTER TABLE Names ADD CONSTRAINT Names_UC UNIQUE (ID, FirstName, LastName);
```

Comment: Thak you for this - much appreciated